# Bash :: append text to output of file

Tags: linux, bash, sed, bash-scripting, ubuntu-16.04

I am very new to Shell Scripting so this maybe a very easy solution but i'm struggling to get it to work.
I have a file with this content:

```
example1.eu 
example2.eu 
example3.eu
```

What I am trying to do is outputing the content of a file to a single line formating to something like this.

> test.example1.eu,test.example2.eu,test.example3.eu

and so on.

I have this on my script but I cant figure how to append "test" for the first entry on the file.

```
cat file | xargs | sed -e 's/ /,test./g'
```

> example1.eu,test.example2.eu,test.example3.eu

Please advise
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use 'paste' for setting delimiter. E.g.

```
cat file | sed -e 's/^/test./' | paste -sd ','
```

Edit: Improved version (tripleee's comment)

```
sed file -e 's/^/test./' | paste -sd ','
```

Comment: The `cat` is useless.  `sed` knows how to read `file` by itself, or use a redirection.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using the `awk` command:

```
 $ awk '{a=a"test."$0","}END{sub(/,$/,"",a);print a}' file
 test.example1.eu,test.example2.eu,test.example3.eu
```

This creates a string variable `a` and appends each line and a comma to the string.  Then it replaces the final comma with nothing and prints the string.

Previous reponse with trailing comma:

```
 $ awk 'BEGIN{ORS=","}{print "test."$0}' file
test.example1.eu,test.example2.eu,test.example3.eu,
```

This sets the Output Record Separator to a comma and then prints each line with `test.` prepended to the string.

Comment: The trailing comma is a bit of a wart. It's not hard to remove but it would not be too hard to avoid in the first place, either. A common pattern is `{ printf "%stest.%s", sep, $0; sep="," }`

Comment: I've updated the response with a new awk command that removes the trailing comma.